# Instruct CMake to choose right version for multiple Boost installation

Tags: boost, cmake

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. My system gives Boost 1.46. Since I had to use the boost lockfree queues, I tried installing 1.59 from the official Boost website. Thus, I actually have 2 versions of boost installed. System default installed in /usr/ & version 1.59 installed in /usr/local.

I have a code base which uses cmake. It is a rather large code base. I am suspecting CMake is still looking at version 1.46. I should I fix it to see version 1.59 in /usr/local.?

My CMakeFiles (relevant portion only):

```
find_package(Boost 1.59 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread date_time)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries( hello_node
                       ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
                       ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                       boost_system
                       boost_thread
                       rt
                       boost_date_time
)

target_link_libraries( dgem
                       ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
                       ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                       boost_system
                       boost_thread
                       rt
                       boost_date_time
)
```

With this the cmake seem to use /usr/include (ie. the older version of boost).

Comment: check which boost version is found by putting a message in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @MertMertce: Why adding a message? It is printed by FindBoost itself. Looking at the output is enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check which boost was found either by having a look at the configure output or in the CMakeCache.txt file in your build directory. The configure output tells you the path where it has found Boost. In the CMakeCache.txt file you can search for BOOST_LIB* or BOOST_INCLUDE* and you should get the path to the library/headers. This will help to identify the version.

If you want to specify one of your two Boost installations, you an pass CMake the root directory of your Boost via `BOOST_ROOT`. This will look like

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1.59 <otherstuff>
```

Comment: seems like -DBOOST_ROOT fixes the problem. Can you update the answer to set this into the CMakeFile.txt please.

Comment: This is not meant to be in your CMakeLists.txt. Probably there are plenty of people having the right version of Boost installed. They are fine, CMake will find their Boost installation. Just you have multiple Boost installations and thus you have to modify the way CMake tries to find Boost. If you are the only user, add `set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/bost_1.59")` one line before `find_package(Boost ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As from the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html), the `FindBoost` module takes the version as an argument along with another parameter called `EXACT`. Unless you set the latter, the former is intended as minimum version and finding a greater one in you system is fine for cmake.

It depends now if it's fine for your project. I cannot say that.

Comment: CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.46.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.59.

Comment: seems like my cmake cannot find the latest version I installed. How should I fix it?

Comment: @mkuse Also from the documentation: "BOOST_ROOT - Preferred installation prefix". So set it to e.g. `"/usr/local"` before searching for Boost?

Comment: At least, show us your cmake file and let us know where the boost lib relies, we cannot be of help otherwise...

Comment: Why do you look for version 1.59 exactly if 1.46 is enough? Put there 1.46 and remove the EXACT statement.

Comment: 1.46 is not enough. I need at least 1.53

Comment: Well, put it there and remove the EXACT, thus  install in your system such a version or greater and set accordingly the BOOST_ROOT parameter. What's wrong? Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score -1):

I directly opened the CMakeCache.txt file and entered the location of the boost local installation in the Boost_INCLUDE_DIR that I needed for a project to avoid interfence with mu usual installation in /usr/local.This worked well and avoids hassle

Comment: But this annoying to do and does only work for oneself.